# Connect SSH, send command and parse to JSON

Tags: node.js, json, ssh

Hello I wrote code to connect to SSH, send command, but sadly I cant figure out how to parse it to JSON.

I've used stringify but sadly it push errors. Same for JSON.parse.

```
const Client = require('ssh2').Client;
const ifconfig = require('ifconfig-parser');

const conn = new Client();
conn.on('ready', function() {
  console.log('Client :: ready');
  conn.exec('ifconfig', function(err, stream) {
    if (err) throw err;
    let data = '';
    stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
      console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
      conn.end();
      const json = ifconfig.parse(data);
      console.log(json);
    }).on('data', function(d) {
      console.log('STDOUT: ' + d);
      data += d;
    }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
    });
  });
}).connect({
  host: '192.168.100.100',
  port: 22,
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password'
});
```

Comment: It might help to remove the console logs and maybe write a comment to show where the issue is occurring, just to make readers' lives easier! :)

Comment: I released a [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/command-to-json) a couple of weeks ago. Maybe it will meet your expectations.